# Image in center of page - resizable

Tags: jquery, html, css

I would like to center an image to center of website.
Than when window resizes i would like to acommplish that image doesent resize, instead of resize its should be cropped left and right by browser window, so that center of image is in vertical center of image.

```
<div class="image-container">
    <img src=imgpath/image.jpg">
</div>
```

I tried this:

```
.image-container img{
   width: 100%;
   min-width: 1440 !important;
   margin: 64px auto 0 auto;
   height: auto;
   min-height: 400px !important;
}

img {
   vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Have any one any ideas how to make this. I would prefere by CSS if not jq should do.

Comment: How many centers has image, according to your post "...so that center of image is in vertical center of image."
What is your goal an image to be centered both vertically and horizontally even when browser is resized and also the image should not resize itself?

Comment: Image has only vertical center. Image shoud not resize, it should be cropped left and right by browser window when resized.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `display:table-cell` to align the inner images to middle of the div.

But in this case you cant give margin because table-cell forces div to act as a td and technically you cant give margin to table td.

So I have added border to div with white color.

```
.image-container{
  background: #C8BFE7;
  text-align: center;
  display:table-cell;
  vertical-align:middle;
  border:white 5px solid
}
```

​

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Arav8/3/